# Modifying edited field of a DetailsView before inserting it to database when in "insert mode"

Tags: asp.net, gridview, data-binding, detailsview

On one of my final year project page I have a DetailsView that I am using to update/edit a GridView.

I have a password field that must show the hashed password.

When I am in "edit" or "insert" mode in the DetailsView and inserting a new password in the field (or editing the field) I would like to hash directly the password before showing it in the GridView/DetailsView and of course before inserting/updating it in the DataBase.

My GridView & DetailsView are both in the same UpdatePanel and I am using a ObjectDataSource.

That a partial code:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsViewSingleUsr" runat="server" Height="50px" 
        Width="125px" DataSourceID="SingleUserObjectDataSource" DataKeyNames="id" 
            onitemdeleted="DetailsViewSingleUsr_ItemDeleted" 
            oniteminserted="DetailsViewSingleUsr_ItemInserted" 
            onitemupdated="DetailsViewSingleUsr_ItemUpdated" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
            oniteminserting="DetailsViewSingleUsr_ItemInserting">
        <Fields>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User ID" InsertVisible="False" 
                SortExpression="id">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("id") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UserName" SortExpression="username">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("username") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("username") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="TextBox1" Display="Dynamic" 
                        ErrorMessage="Username may only contain alphanumeric characters" 
                        ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" 
                        ErrorMessage="UserName already exist." SetFocusOnError="True" Display="Dynamic" 
                        ControlToValidate="TextBox1" onservervalidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("username") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="firstname">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("firstname") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("firstname") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("firstname") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="lastname">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("lastname") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("lastname") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("lastname") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Password" SortExpression="pass">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pass") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pass") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pass") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Score" SortExpression="currentScore">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("currentScore") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("currentScore") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("currentScore") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Best Score" SortExpression="maxScore">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("maxScore") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("maxScore") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("maxScore") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                        CommandName="Update" ImageUrl="~/images/update.png" />
                    &nbsp;<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                        CommandName="Cancel" ImageUrl="~/images/cancel.png" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                        CommandName="Insert" ImageUrl="~/images/insert.png" />
                    &nbsp;<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                        CommandName="Cancel" ImageUrl="~/images/cancel.png" />
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                        CommandName="Edit" ImageUrl="~/images/edit.png" />
                    &nbsp;<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                        CommandName="New" ImageUrl="~/images/new.png"/>
                    &nbsp;<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                        CommandName="Delete" ImageUrl="~/images/delete.png"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ControlStyle Height="20px" Width="20px" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Fields>
    </asp:DetailsView>
```

I am able to access the password textbox in the code behind in the "ItemInserting" Event with that code:

```
protected void DetailsViewSingleUsr_ItemInserting(object sender, DetailsViewInsertEventArgs e)
{
    DetailsView myDetailsView = (DetailsView)sender;
    if (myDetailsView.CurrentMode == DetailsViewMode.Insert)
    {
        Label9.Text = ((TextBox)myDetailsView.FindControl("TextBox4")).Text;

    }
}
```

But how can I modify? Am I on the right way? Any suggestions?

Thx a lot guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListViewInsertEventArgs contains property [Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listviewinserteventargs.values%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), in which you can find all of inserting values, obtained from controls. You may just modify those data. For example

```
e.Values["password"] = "newpassword";
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks! I've finally end up with this code:

```
protected void DetailsViewSingleUsr_ItemInserting(object sender, DetailsViewInsertEventArgs e)
{
    e.Values["pass"] = LoginSecurityLogic.Hash_Password_to_MD5(e.Values["pass"].ToString());
}

protected void DetailsViewSingleUsr_ItemUpdating(object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
        e.NewValues["pass"] = LoginSecurityLogic.Hash_Password_to_MD5(e.NewValues["pass"].ToString());

}
```